# Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, hikaricp

After successfully running application, I'm facing a connection error. My code is following.  Am I using efficient connection handling, or do I need to improve it? Where can I saw my active, used and idle connection status while running application?

```
@Service
public class printChallan extends JdbcDaoSupport{

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@PostConstruct
private void initialize() {setDataSource(dataSource);}

public boolean printAdmissionForm(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    try {
            conn = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
            //conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            jasperdesign = JRXmlLoader.load(totalPath);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperdesign);
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, conn);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
           if(conn != null) conn.close(); // Does I need to close Connection Manually
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return true;
}
public boolean callProcedure(HttpServletRequest request){
CallableStatement cs = null;
try 
{
   cs = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection()   // does this connection need to be closed.
   .prepareCall("{? = call FUNC_CHALLAN_PRINT_TYPE(?)}");
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.setString(2, challanNbr);
    cs.execute();
    Status = cs.getString(1);
    cs.close();
    return Status;
} catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.debug("Error occured while getting Challan record" + e.getMessage());
}finally
{

}
return true;
}
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.10.37:1521:ORCL
spring.datasource.username=app
spring.datasource.password=app
spring.datasource.platform=ORACLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't closing connections, the pool will be full and you will get timeout when trying to get new connection.

You aren't closing connection, simply change to try-with-resources so it'll be closed automatically

```
try (java.sql.Connection conn = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection()) {
```

Same solution for `CallableStatement`